# UiPath - how to use variables in switch/case

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I'm just curious about switch/case in UiPath.
Everywhere else in UiPath, strings must have double quotes or stored in variables, however in switch/case, it seems different.

Every "case" is interpreted as string, regardles of the quotes.
How to use variables in there when they're interpreted as string?

Comment: You can't set a variable in Case, as a workaround you can check this: https://forum.uipath.com/t/switch-case-with-variable-at-case/234560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use variable in switch case in UiPath. However you can use following expression in Expression property helps switch dynamically.

Array.IndexOf({var1,var2,var3},item.ToString)

Something like below screenshot

[image: Variable in Switch Case]

Hope this helps